# Transform a multi-index into dictionary without loop

Tags: python, multi-index

I have a multiindex of this kind:

```
multiindex = 
[(10, 24016),
 (10, 24042),
 (10, 24130),
 (20, 33457),
 (20, 34339),
 (20, 34598),
 (20, 34754)]
```

and I want to obtain from each values of the first index a list of other values linked in the second index. In my example I want something like this (not especially a dict)

```
{10: [24016, 24042, 24130], 20: [33457, 34339, 34598, 34754]}
```

I've tried lot of things (like transform in dict, unzip it, etc.), I can do that with a loop but as my multi-index is huge I want to avoid it.

Did someone know a way to do this easily ?

Comment: Share the code showing your trials.

Comment: How are you doing it with a loop? And what makes you think it is inefficient? Show your code so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `itertools.groupby`:

```
groups = {k: [i[1] for i in list(g)] for k,g in groupby(multiindex, lambda x: x[0])}
print(groups)
```

Output:

```
{10: [24016, 24042, 24130], 20: [33457, 34339, 34598, 34754]}
```